# How to use texture image .jpg as Windows.Media.pen C#

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, kinect, drawingcontext

I have a texture image as .jpg and I want to use this image as Windows.Media.pen

I use Windows.Media.pen for drawing skeleton data in DrawingContext which I got it from microsoft kinect.

How can I use texture image .jpg as Windows.Media.pen?

---

solved the problem.

```
ImageSource image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"...\texture.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
var brush = new ImageBrush(image);
var pen = new Pen(brush, 10);
drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, XPos, YPos);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :D

Not sure if you'd get what you've been expecting as you can see below but here's how to do it :

You need to use [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be able to assign an image to a `Pen`.

Original image :

[image]

Result :

[image]

Code :

```
ImageSource image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\..\5c5f910416e2b92bb73fa59c56fe695d.png", UriKind.Relative));
var brush = new ImageBrush(image);
var pen = new Pen(brush, 50);
var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, pen, new Rect(new Size(200, 200)));
}

var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);
Content = new Image {Source = renderTargetBitmap, Stretch = Stretch.None};
```